# functional interfaces of java 8 in java 7

Tags: java, compatibility, java-7, java-8

are the functional interfaces of java 8 available somewhere (i.e. a jar) so I can use them in a Java 7 project? that way I could later on easier port the code to idiomatic java 8. if not, is that technically possible or do they make use of new features like default methods?

yes, i meant the interfaces in java.util.function. since adding packages with the java prefix seems to be disallowed importing them from somewhere else is not an option.

Comment: Which interface are you interested in? Any interface that defines a single method is a functional interface, but the concept is not too useful without lambda expressions

Comment: It's basically that particular case of the Strategy pattern where the implementor classes implement only one abstract method. In Java 8 it's just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A functional interface is simply an interface with only one non-default, non-static method. All interfaces that satisfy that definition can be implemented through a lambda in Java 8.

For example, `Runnable` is a functional interface and in Java 8 you can write: `Runnable r = () -> doSomething();`.

Many of the functional interfaces brought by Java 8 are in [the `java.util.function` package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html). The most common are:

- `Consumer<T>` which has a `void accept(T t)`
- `Supplier<T>` which has a `T get()`
- `Function<T, R>` which has a `R apply(T t)`
- `Predicate<T>` which as a `boolean test(T t)`

---

What you could do at this stage is to use single method interfaces wherever it makes sense, if possible with similar signatures. When you migrate to Java 8 you will be able to easily refactor through your IDE from:

```
someMethod(new MyConsumer<T>() { public void accept(T t) { use(t); } });
```

into

```
someMethod(t -> use(t));
```

Then change the signature of `someMethod(MyConsumer<T> mc)` into `someMethod(Consumer<T> c)`, get rid of you `MyConsumer` interface and you are done.

Comment: To add onto it, the interface needs to have one and only one non-default and non-static method. (Static methods are also allowed in functional interfaces)

Comment: @skiwi indeed amended.

Comment: Since your own interfaces have to reside in a different `package` (you are not allowed to add to `java. …`), you can even name it `Consumer` rather than `MyConsumer`. And if the signature matches exactly, you can turn your own `Consumer` into a sub-interface of `java.util.function.Consumer` when migrating to Java 8.

Comment: As most answers here, this misses an important point. Doing so probably violates the JDK license if you ship this with a proprietary software.

Comment: @jherek that would be a stretch considering that we are talking about well known patterns (supplier, consumer etc) with no implementation. But then IANAL...

Comment: Tell that to Oracle lawyers. The famous Google vs Oracle lawsuit, which has been going on for more than a decade, is precisely on whether API interfaces are protected by the license or not.

Answer (score 10):

Here are the signatures of java 8 main functional interfaces as an addition to assylias answer

```
public interface Consumer<T> {
    void accept(T t);
}

public interface Supplier<T> {
    T get();
}

public interface Function<T, R> {
    R apply(T t);
}

public interface Predicate<T> {
    boolean test(T t);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Java 8 functional interfaces are limited.  Use the FunctionalJava types P1, F, F2, F3, ..., F8, TryCatch0, TryCatch1, ..., TryCatch8 to do the same thing now with more functionality.

https://functionaljava.ci.cloudbees.com/job/master/javadoc/

You can use the Retro Lambda project to compile with Java 8 and lambdas, but target the Java 7 VM.  This avoids the whole anonymous inner class nonsense.  See the FunctionalJava project for an example (http://www.functionaljava.org/).

Comment: They are limited for a reason. A generic 8-params function with 8 generic parameters is almost guaranteed to confuse whoever runs into that code.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by @assylias which I think solves the problem in most cases, there is one more option, and that is, to make your own `@FunctionalInterface` and keep it that way.

It depends on where you use the functions. All of the aforementioned interfaces can be used by JDK utility classes. `Predicate` allows filtering, `Supplier` allows object creation, `Function` allows mapping ... In fact, `Predicate` and `Supplier` are rather straighforward, but `Function` and `Consumer` can be often unclear, especially `BiFunction`. They can also tie your hands in some use cases.

You can write your own interface that has any amount of inputs, throws checked exceptions, has generics only where you need them and its name says what it should be used for.

```
//@FunctionalInterface
public interface MyCustomInterface {
    <T> MyCustomOutput myCustomAction(MyCustomInput<T> str) throws MyCustomException;
}
```

So, while the interfaces provided with JDK are useful, sometimes you might prefer to keep your own solution even in Java 8, just with the annotations, and lambdas instead of anonymous classes.

Answer (score 0):

There were few interfaces in Java 7 that can be termed as functional interface since they had only one abstract method which are Runnable, ActionListener, Comparable.
Java 8 came with more functional interfaces like Function, Predicate, Consumer and Supplier.